# Can't Login into my Secure Login Script PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I've recently started to learn PHP, and was trying to create a secure Login following this guide http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL.

Everything seems to work fine for me apart from the login(). Which I tweaked a bit.
I put some echos to try to pin point the error, it returns an error on the password compare IF:

The function returns : *Login function error 1*

The function login located in includes/functions.php :

```
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);

    if ($db_password == $password) {
                echo "Password is correct!";
```

The sha512.js is from here pajhome.org. uk/crypt/md5/sha512 .html,
and the form from the above mentioned WikiHow.

The connection isn't a problem has i use the same connection to insert into MySQL and it works.

Thanks for the attention given to my problem and if i didn't disclose enough info please advice.

EDIT: deleted a lot of code, as @SeanWM commented i shouldn't expect no one to go through all the code.

@Robert Rozas Thank you for the help. the passwords are indeed mismatching.
The output is:

Login function error 1 c2d872cb4c6a1b3c22ce35fb9dc0dfca14aa6d48 vs c2d872cb4c6a1b3c22ce35fb9dc0dfca14aa6d48cc2e8c3dcf02c87a3dfb7e3fec2a098b932c11655960e43bb89af058220ff8d75c666fe57ef7206b74d5f9af

Please have a look at how the password is constructed:

It goes from the register form to .js:

```
   // Add the new element to our form. 
   form.appendChild(p);
   p.name = "p";
   p.type = "hidden";
   p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
```

and then through php:

```
   $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

   // Create a random salt
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);
```

and then inserted into MySQL. If you could please point me again in the correct direction i would appreciate.

EDIT 2: Thanks to the input from @Second Rikudo it worked after removing the double hashing

But in light of the comments from Second Rikudo "sha512 is not secure" 
and @tadman "That tutorial is worryingly incomplete and uses hazardously bad practices" 
I've decided to revise the code utilizing https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat 
as advised by Second Rikudo.

Comment: Just to let you know, I didn't even bother reading this. Please don't post all your code and ask us to fix it. Try to narrow down the issue so it's a little more specific. You should read though [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SeanWM you and 18 other viewers at the time of this comment =)

Comment: If you can't log in, then I guess it really is secure.

Comment: echo "Login function error 1 ".$db_password." vs ".$password."<br>";....and post the output

Comment: That tutorial is worryingly incomplete and uses hazardously bad practices like string interpolation instead of being strict about using SQL placeholders. Why are you building your own login system when a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) would provide one for you?

Comment: @tadman: Because [there's nothing wrong with reinventing the wheel.](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/08/reinvent-wheel.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I am mistaken, but you are hashing the password twice upon registering (once with JavaScript, and once with PHP), but when you login, you only hash once (with PHP).

As a sidenote, **sha512 is *not* secure**. Upgrade yourself to PHP5.5 to make use of **[`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** and other password functions.

If you cannot upgrade, see **[ircmaxell's library for forward compatibility with those functions](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)** (He is practically the one who added `password_*()` into PHP, so his library is good).

Comment: Thanks for your input Rikudo Sennin ^^. It worked in the end after i took off the double hashing. But I'm going to follow your advice and revise my code utilizing ircmaxell's library.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu: Great to hear! If you answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on the large green tickmark below the question score. That will mark the question as complete.