# Cannot login with secure login wikihow

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i created the secure login with www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL . The register is success, but the login was failed. 
This is my **functions.php** code :

```
<?php
    function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
        // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
                      FROM users 
                                      WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
            $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            // get variables from result.
            $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
            $stmt->fetch();

            // hash the password with the unique salt.
            $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
                // from too many login attempts 
                if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                    // Account is locked 
                    // Send an email to user saying their account is locked 
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // Check if the password in the database matches 
                    // the password the user submitted.
                    if ($db_password == $password) {
                        // Password is correct!
                        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                        // XSS protection as we might print this value
                        $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                        // XSS protection as we might print this value
                        $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                        // Login successful. 
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // Password is not correct 
                        // We record this attempt in the database 
                        $now = time();
                        if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) 
                                        VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: login_attempts");
                            exit();
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // No user exists. 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Could not create a prepared statement
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

and this is my **register.inc.php** code

```
    <?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error</p>';
    }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, salt, registerdate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $date);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
                exit();
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

and this is the **forms.js** code :

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
}
```

EDIT :
my **proccess_login.php**

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header("Location: ../protected_page.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Could not process login');
    exit();
}
```

i already create the user email : xxx@gmail.com and the password is Xxx123
the registration show success, but the login show wrong. what's the wrong with the code?
i have try to try this question [Can't Login into my Secure Login Script PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155584/cant-login-into-my-secure-login-script-php-and-mysql) . i already remove the double hasing in **register.inc.php** :

```
// Create a random salt
$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

// Create salted password 
$password = $password . $random_salt;
```

what's the wrong with my code? thank you

Comment: You have `INSERT INTO usermining ...` but `SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM users ...`? Shouldn't those table names match?

Comment: ok, that's my fault, but i have change the code. and still not working